# How to make an app always open with root permission in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, root

I just simply want to click the app icon, give the root password and use it.

Is there any way to make this happen? I am using Debian 9 Cinnamon.

Comment: Configure your app icon to call `gksudo <application-name>`, or a script to that effect, instead of the application itself. Warning: If you are running graphical applications as root, you are very probably doing it wrong. Graphical applications *shouldn't* require root rights.

Answer (score 0):

Add set-user-bit and change the app's owner to root will solve your problem.

```
sudo chmod u+s /path/to/app
sudo chown root /path/to/app
```

BR,